# Intuitive explanation on why velocity = 0 for a inverted pendulum on a wheel system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, conservation-laws

**I believe I have solved below problem. I am not looking for help on problem-solving per se. I am just looking for an intuitive explanation.**

Problem statement: wheel mass = $m_1$, even mass rod BC mass = $m_2$. rod length = $2l$. Rod hingers on wheel so wheel can move freely. rod started falling due to a small perturbation. Wheel started rolling without slipping (so there is a frictional force, but the work of the frictional force can be ignored). When rod is at horizontal position, what's the velocity of wheel C and the angular velocity of the stick w.r.t. C?

[image]

Let $x$ be the coordinate of the wheel. $\theta$ be the angle between the rod and the vertical line. Let $A$ be the center of $BC$. Then

$x_A = x + l \sin \theta$, $y_A = l \cos \theta$, $\dot{x_A} = \dot{x} + l \cos \theta \dot{\theta}$, $\dot{y_A} = -l \sin \theta \dot{\theta}$

Kinetic energy consists of the horizontal movement of the wheel, the falling rod, and the rotation of the wheel:

\begin{align}
T & = \frac{1}{2} m_v v_C^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} m_1 R^2 (\frac{v_C}{R})^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_v v_A^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12} m_2 (2l)^2 \dot{\theta}^2\\
& = (\frac{3}{4} m_1 + \frac{1}{2} m_2) \dot{x}^2 + \frac{2}{3} m_2 l^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + m_2 l \dot{\theta} \dot{x} \cos \theta\\
\end{align}

$$V = m_2 g \cos \theta l$$

$$T+V = m_2 gl$$

It looks intimidating, but here is a trick. $L = T-V$ doesn't have $x$ so from Lagrange Equation, $$\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot {x}}) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$$

we have $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = C $ a constant. So we can get $\dot{x} = 0, \dot{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{3g}{2l}}$, when $\theta = 90^{\circ}$.

**But is there an intuitive explanation of why $\dot{x} = 0$?**

If this is not a wheel, but rather a block or a cart on a frictionless surface, then this explanation would be trivial. The momentum conserves on the horizontal direction.

But since there is a wheel that's rolling without slipping, there is always a frictional force to one direction from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 90$, and we can't use the conservation of the momentum here. How do we intuitively explain  $\dot{x} = 0$?

Comment: If friction was negligible, the answer would be obvious; there would be no external horizontal force on the stick + wheel system, so horizontal momentum is conserved; hence when the stick's axis is horizontal, its center of mass has no horizontal velocity and thus the same can be said of the wheel. However, there's friction here which makes it less easy. But, my suspicion is that friction points in one direction for one phase of motion, and switches direction in the other phase of motion, which "cancels out" and allows horizontal momentum to be preserved.

Comment: You can see it with this transformation$~x_A\mapsto x_A-v\,t~$, hence the equation of motion Newton second law doesn’t chance. where the velocity v is constant and $~x=v\,t$